# Get current module inside FunctionPass llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a function pass in LLVM and need to call the method Module::getOrInsertFunction. I need to access the module of the current function. How do I get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use getParent() function: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html#a9e1fc23a17e97d2d1732e753ae9251ac

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to: http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html
According to the documentation here, 
To be explicit, FunctionPass subclasses are not allowed to:
1. Inspect or modify a Function other than the one currently being processed.
**2. Add or remove Functions from the current Module.**
3. Add or remove global variables from the current Module.
4. Maintain state across invocations of runOnFunction (including global data).

So, you cannot call getOrInsertFunction from inside a FunctionPass. You will need a ModulePass